# Why (Qt 5.15.2) STL-Style Reverse Iterators cannot be used for print from begin to end?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, iterator

I am trying to use STL-style iterators in  Qt. When I build for loop:

```cpp
for(auto i = list.rbegin(); i != list.rend(); ++i)
{ }
```

it works but if I build like:

```cpp
for(auto i = list.rend(); i != list.rbegin(); --i)
{ }
```

it doesn't work and gives an error. I wonder why can't i use reverse iterator from start to end. Any explanation or source will be helpful.

```cpp
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>


int main() {
    QList<QString> list;
    list << "A" << "V" << "C" << "D";

    // this works
    for(auto i = list.rbegin() ; i != list.rend(); ++i) 
    { }

    // error: this doesn't work
    for(auto i = list.rend(); i != list.rbegin(); --i) 
    {
        *i = i-> toLower();
        qDebug() << *i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the error a secret? "It doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: Unless `QList<...>` is odd, the iteration itself should work. Accessing the data is different: reverse iteration isn't symmetric to forward iteration as you'll need to decrement before accessing the value.

Comment: @DietmarKühl [Dereferencing a reverse iterator does that for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator*); the problem is in dereferencing the one-past-the-end iterator. In that sense, it's just the same as for any other kind of iterator.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `reverse_iterator`, indeed, provides a reversed view when used with forward iteration. Hovever, reverse iteration, i.e., traversing using `—it` instead of `++it` needs to first step (`—it`) before the dereference (`*it`) to avoid accessing the value of the _past the end_-iterator - independent of the iterator type used.

Comment: @DietmarKühl That's correct, and what my answer says ;) I think we're saying the same thing, but the OP's strange choice to reverse-iterate a reverse iterator range has led to some confusing conflicts in terminology :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I am sorry if am not clear enough, I am a little bit new to programming. Thanks

Comment: Now I check errors but it just says: 08:43:29: The program has unexpectedly finished.
08:43:29: The process was ended forcefully.

Answer (score 4):

You can't dereference the past-the-end iterator. This is not unique to reverse iterators.

This would be correct:

```
if (!list.empty())
{
   for (i = list.rend()-1; ; --i)
   {
       // your code here
       
       if (i == list.rbegin())
          break;
   }
}
```

… but it's pretty ugly.

If you want to reverse the direction of your loop, switch from reverse iterators back to normal ones:

```
QList<QString>::iterator i;
for (i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
{
   // your code here
}
```

This ugliness is the reason we have reverse iterators in the first place.

Comment: @Ghasem Ramezani Thanks for your suggestion, but this is a great example of why AAA is silly cargo-culting. `auto` here _hides the type_, and the whole point of this Q&A is the iterator type. We want to see it. We need to see it. Exchanging it for `auto` in this answer accomplishes nothing but obfuscation and box-ticking, neither of which is useful.

Comment: I know the iterators but I just want to try reverse iterator. By the way, thank you.